# Merge 2 or more nested dictionaries into 1 and arrange Items in custom order

Tags: json, excel, vba, dictionary, collections

I am new to dictionaries. I am pulling data from an external website that outputs a JSON string containing Initiative Level data that i parse using VBA-JSON code found [here](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON). This JSON parser outputs a JSON Dictionary object containing nested dictionaries and collections.

```
{
  "respCode": 200,
  "respMessage": "OK",
  "response": [
    {
      "INIT_ID": 1234567,
      "INIT_NAME": "SOME INIT NAME",
      "CATE": "PERFUMED WATER",
      "CTRY": "GB",
      "OPEN_DATE": "2016-02-10 00:00:00",
      "ITEMS": [
        {
          "ITEM_ID": "44556677",
          "ITEM_DSCR": "ABC CO, PERFUMED WATER,CARBONATED,AMBIENT,,,,CAFFEINE,PLASTIC,PACK,250ML"
        },
        {
          "ITEM_ID": "45566778",
          "ITEM_DSCR": "ABC CO, PERFUMED WATER,CARBONATED,CRYSTAL,,,,CAFFEINE,GLASS,PACK,270ML"
        },
        {
          "ITEM_ID": "46576879",
          "ITEM_DSCR": "ABC CO, PERFUMED WATER,NON-CARBONATED,AMBIENT,,,,NON-CAFFEINE,TETRA,PACK,275ML"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Since there are 3 Items in this Initiative, i have to pull the Attributes data for these 3 Items again from the external website using another 3 API calls -
 the responses again are JSON strings, that i have to parse using VBA-JSON to get a Dictionary object containing nested dictionaries and collections like this:

ITEM 1:

```
{
  "respCode": 200,
  "respMessage": "OK",
  "response": [
    {
      "ITEM CODE": "44556677",
      "ITEM DESCRIPTION": "ABC CO, PERFUMED WATER,CARBONATED,AMBIENT,,,,CAFFEINE,PLASTIC,PACK,250ML",
      "ATTR DETAILS": [
        {
          "ATTR ID": "25",
          "ATTR DESCRIPTION": "MOD_NAME",
          "ATTR_VAL ID": "22222222",
          "ATTR_VAL DESCRIPTION": "PERFUMED WATER  - CARBONATED - CAFFIENE"
        },
        {
          "ATTR ID": "45",
          "ATTR DESCRIPTION": "PROM ACTIVE",
          "ATTR_VAL ID": "44444444",
          "ATTR_VAL DESCRIPTION": "NO PROMO"
        },
        {
          "ATTR ID": "38",
          "ATTR DESCRIPTION": "BRAND",
          "ATTR_VAL ID": "99999999",
          "ATTR_VAL DESCRIPTION": "KANE & ABEL"
        },
        {
          "ATTR ID": "51",
          "ATTR DESCRIPTION": "WEIGHT/VOLUME",
          "ATTR_VAL ID": "66666666",
          "ATTR_VAL DESCRIPTION": "250ML"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

ITEM 2:

```
{
  "respCode": 200,
  "respMessage": "OK",
  "response": [
    {
      "ITEM CODE": "45566778",
      "ITEM DESCRIPTION": "ABC CO, PERFUMED WATER,CARBONATED,CRYSTAL,,,,CAFFEINE,GLASS,PACK,270ML",
      "ATTR DETAILS": [
        {
          "ATTR ID": "25",
          "ATTR DESCRIPTION": "MOD_NAME",
          "ATTR_VAL ID": "22222222",
          "ATTR_VAL DESCRIPTION": "PERFUMED WATER, CRYSTAL  - CARBONATED - CAFFIENE"
        },
        {
          "ATTR ID": "45",
          "ATTR DESCRIPTION": "PROM ACTIVE",
          "ATTR_VAL ID": "44444444",
          "ATTR_VAL DESCRIPTION": "PROMO"
        },
        {
          "ATTR ID": "38",
          "ATTR DESCRIPTION": "BRAND",
          "ATTR_VAL ID": "99999999",
          "ATTR_VAL DESCRIPTION": "BEAUTY & BEAST"
        },
        {
          "ATTR ID": "51",
          "ATTR DESCRIPTION": "WEIGHT/VOLUME",
          "ATTR_VAL ID": "66666666",
          "ATTR_VAL DESCRIPTION": "270ML"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

ITEM 3:

```
{
  "respCode": 200,
  "respMessage": "OK",
  "response": [
    {
      "ITEM CODE": "46576879",
      "ITEM DESCRIPTION": "ABC CO, PERFUMED WATER,NON-CARBONATED,AMBIENT,,,,NON-CAFFEINE,TETRA,PACK,275ML",
      "ATTR DETAILS": [
        {
          "ATTR ID": "25",
          "ATTR DESCRIPTION": "MOD_NAME",
          "ATTR_VAL ID": "22222222",
          "ATTR_VAL DESCRIPTION": "PERFUMED WATER  - NON-CARBONATED - NON-CAFFIENE"
        },
        {
          "ATTR ID": "45",
          "ATTR DESCRIPTION": "PROM ACTIVE",
          "ATTR_VAL ID": "44444444",
          "ATTR_VAL DESCRIPTION": "NO PROMO"
        },
        {
          "ATTR ID": "38",
          "ATTR DESCRIPTION": "BRAND",
          "ATTR_VAL ID": "99999999",
          "ATTR_VAL DESCRIPTION": "HENSEL & GRETEL"
        },
        {
          "ATTR ID": "51",
          "ATTR DESCRIPTION": "WEIGHT/VOLUME",
          "ATTR_VAL ID": "66666666",
          "ATTR_VAL DESCRIPTION": "275ML"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

> What i want to do is : Merge the 3 Items dictionaries with the 1st Initiative Dictionary such that each Item Attributes gets merged for each Item specified by its Item ID like this:

Final Dictionary:

```
    {
  "respCode": 200,
  "respMessage": "OK",
  "response": [
    {
      "INIT_ID": 1234567,
      "INIT_NAME": "SOME INIT NAME",
      "CATE": "PERFUMED WATER",
      "CTRY": "GB",
      "OPEN_DATE": "2016-02-10 00:00:00",
      "ITEMS": [
        {
          "ITEM_ID": "44556677",
          "ITEM_DSCR": "ABC CO, PERFUMED WATER,CARBONATED,AMBIENT,,,,CAFFEINE,PLASTIC,PACK,250ML"
          "ATTR DETAILS": [
              {
               "ATTR ID": "25",
               "ATTR DESCRIPTION": "MOD_NAME",
               "ATTR_VAL ID": "22222222",
               "ATTR_VAL DESCRIPTION": "PERFUMED WATER  - CARBONATED - CAFFIENE"
             },
             {
               "ATTR ID": "45",
               "ATTR DESCRIPTION": "PROM ACTIVE",
               "ATTR_VAL ID": "44444444",
               "ATTR_VAL DESCRIPTION": "NO PROMO"
             },
             {
               "ATTR ID": "38",
               "ATTR DESCRIPTION": "BRAND",
               "ATTR_VAL ID": "99999999",
               "ATTR_VAL DESCRIPTION": "KANE & ABEL"
             },
             {
               "ATTR ID": "51",
               "ATTR DESCRIPTION": "WEIGHT/VOLUME",
               "ATTR_VAL ID": "66666666",
               "ATTR_VAL DESCRIPTION": "250ML"
             }
          ]
        },

        {
          "ITEM_ID": "45566778",
          "ITEM_DSCR": "ABC CO, PERFUMED WATER,CARBONATED,CRYSTAL,,,,CAFFEINE,GLASS,PACK,270ML"
          "ATTR DETAILS": [
            {
              "ATTR ID": "25",
              "ATTR DESCRIPTION": "MOD_NAME",
              "ATTR_VAL ID": "22222222",
              "ATTR_VAL DESCRIPTION": "PERFUMED WATER, CRYSTAL  - CARBONATED - CAFFIENE"
            },
            {
              "ATTR ID": "45",
              "ATTR DESCRIPTION": "PROM ACTIVE",
              "ATTR_VAL ID": "44444444",
              "ATTR_VAL DESCRIPTION": "PROMO"
            },
            {
              "ATTR ID": "38",
              "ATTR DESCRIPTION": "BRAND",
              "ATTR_VAL ID": "99999999",
              "ATTR_VAL DESCRIPTION": "BEAUTY & BEAST"
            },
            {
              "ATTR ID": "51",
              "ATTR DESCRIPTION": "WEIGHT/VOLUME",
              "ATTR_VAL ID": "66666666",
              "ATTR_VAL DESCRIPTION": "270ML"
            }
          ]
        },

        {
          "ITEM_ID": "46576879",
          "ITEM_DSCR": "ABC CO, PERFUMED WATER,NON-CARBONATED,AMBIENT,,,,NON-CAFFEINE,TETRA,PACK,275ML"
          "ATTR DETAILS": [
            {
              "ATTR ID": "25",
              "ATTR DESCRIPTION": "MOD_NAME",
              "ATTR_VAL ID": "22222222",
              "ATTR_VAL DESCRIPTION": "PERFUMED WATER  - NON-CARBONATED - NON-CAFFIENE"
            },
            {
              "ATTR ID": "45",
              "ATTR DESCRIPTION": "PROM ACTIVE",
              "ATTR_VAL ID": "44444444",
              "ATTR_VAL DESCRIPTION": "NO PROMO"
            },
            {
              "ATTR ID": "38",
              "ATTR DESCRIPTION": "BRAND",
              "ATTR_VAL ID": "99999999",
              "ATTR_VAL DESCRIPTION": "HENSEL & GRETEL"
            },
            {
              "ATTR ID": "51",
              "ATTR DESCRIPTION": "WEIGHT/VOLUME",
              "ATTR_VAL ID": "66666666",
              "ATTR_VAL DESCRIPTION": "275ML"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Finally i want to loop through the Final Dictionary and display the 3 Items details in 3 Columns on a worksheet like this:

[image]

Can someone guide me on how to do this?

EDIT: Here is what i could figure out.....but blanks have to be filled....

```
Sub GetJSON()
Dim XMLhttp As Object, oJSON As Object, oRTN As Object
Dim URL1$
Dim arrItemIDs() As Variant


Set oRTN = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
oRTN.comparemode = vbTextCompare

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
With ThisWorkbook
    Set wsMain = .Sheets("Main")
    Set wsOut = .Sheets("Output")

    URL = "http://11.27.141.15:8000/dev/getInit?" _
      & "email=" & "abc@gmail.com" & "&country=" & "GB" & "&initid=" & "1234567"

    Set XMLhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    With XMLhttp
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
        .Send

        If XMLhttp.ReadyState = 4 And XMLhttp.Status = 200 Then
            Set oJSON = ParseJson(XMLhttp.ResponseText)

           ' ******CODE TO BE WRITTEN TO COLLECT THE ITEM IDs IN AN ARRAY*****
            arrItemIDs = RecurseDictionary(oJSON)


           ' *****************************
            For x = LBound(arrItemIDs) To UBound(arrItemIDs)
                URL = "http://11.27.141.15:8000/dev/getItemAttr?" _
                & "email=" & "abc@gmail.com" & "&country=" & "GB" & "&itemid=" & arrItemIDs(x)
                Set XMLhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
                With XMLhttp
                    .Open "GET", URL, False
                    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
                    .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
                    .Send

                    If XMLhttp.ReadyState = 4 And XMLhttp.Status = 200 Then
                                Set oJSON = ParseJson(XMLhttp.ResponseText)
                        ' ******CODE TO BE WRITTEN TO MERGE EACH ITEMS ATTRIBUTES JSON TO EARLIER INITIATIVES JSON *****


                        ' *****************************
                    End If
                End With
            Next x

            ' ******CODE TO BE WRITTEN TO DUMP MERGED ARRAY OR DIC ON TO SHEET*****
            i = 1
            wsOut.Cells.ClearContents


            ' *****************************

        End If
    End With
End With
```

Comment: What do you have so far ?  Where specifically are you having a problem ?  Do you really need to merge the dictionaries, or just produce the output sheet?

Comment: @TimWilliams i am not sure how i can create the output as i have not worked with json objects or dictionaries before. since there are multiple items in an initiative, so multiple api calls to download their json. hence i thought the final json has to be a merged one.

Comment: Unless you already have code to render the merged version to a worksheet it just seems like extra work - just fetch each item as you need it.  What you're wanting to do isn't that simple though so unless you've started with some code it's unlikely people here will jump in and write it for you.

Comment: @TimWilliams i have edited OP to add some code as per how i understood flow. Let me know if it is the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

This might get you started:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim Json As Object, itm As Object, itemDetails, k, s As String
    Dim initiatives, initiative, items, itmId, details

    'I'm storing the JSON on a worksheet for testing purposes...
    Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(Sheet1.Range("A1").Value)

    Set initiatives = Json("response") '<< array of inititatives

    For Each initiative In initiatives

        'Top-level info....
        Debug.Print initiative("INIT_ID")
        Debug.Print initiative("INIT_NAME")
        Debug.Print initiative("CATE")
        'etc....

        'list info on ITEMS (as a a collection)
        Set items = initiative("ITEMS")

        For Each itm In items
            'itm is a Dictionary
            itmId = itm("ITEM_ID")
            Debug.Print "Item: " & itmId
            'here's where you'd fetch the details using item id...
            Set itemDetails = JsonConverter.ParseJson(Sheet1.Range("B1").Value)("response")(1)
            Set details = itemDetails("ATTR DETAILS")
            Debug.Print details.Count

        Next itm

    Next

End Sub
```

I would factor out the request/response/parsing into a stand-alone function:

```
'return a parsed JSON object given a URL
Function GetJsonObject(URL As String)
    Dim XMLhttp As Object, oJSON As Object
    Set XMLhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    With XMLhttp
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
        .Send
        If .ReadyState = 4 And .Status = 200 Then
            Set oJSON = ParseJson(.ResponseText)
        End If
    End With
    Set GetJsonObject = oJSON
End Function
```

Comment: there is only 1 Initiative which could have multiple items. Also, if you look at the sheet pic, the ATTR_DESCRIPTION becomes the key and the ATTR_VAL_DESCRIPTION becomes the Value.

Comment: The first json has "response" as an array: if there can ever be only one element in that array then that simplifies the code.  That should get you started though.

Comment: I found out that the ParseJson function returns a Dictionary containing Nested Dictionaries and Collections (not Arrays). So while looping one would require a recursive function to check if Key is a dictionary or a collection, inorder to grab the keys & values. How can one write such a function?

Comment: You already know the format and structure of your data, from looking at the Json:  [] is a Collection and {} is a Dictionary

Comment: i have written recursive code to add initiative + all items to a single dictionary, but facing problem when the key's value is itself a Dictionary. Secondly, another hiccup i found is in ITEMS collection which contains multiple dictionaries, the keys are the same in each of them e.g. ATTR_ID. So the values get overwritten with a single ATTR_ID key. Third, the "ATTR_DESCRIPTION" key's Value is to be added as Key, and its Value should be the "ATTR_VALDESCRIPTION". I want to add these to the same single Dictionary.

Comment: i have written recursive code to add initiative + all items to single dictionary, but facing problem when the key's value is itself a Dictionary. 2ndly, another prob i found is in ITEMS collection which contains multiple dictionaries - keys are same in each e.g. ATTR_ID. So values get overwritten with single ATTR_ID key. Somewhere on SO, was said to create new temp Dict, add to it. then assign temp Dict to original dictionary. How? 3rd, the "ATTR_DESCRIPTION" key's Value is to be added as Key, and its Value should be the "ATTR_VALDESCRIPTION". I want to add these to the same single Dictionary.

Comment: Why are you re-arranging your data like this if (1) the structure and type of content is known in advance and (2) your main aim is to populate the data on a worksheet and not to create some alternate data structure for (eg) storage purposes?  You can write out the data directly from the existing structures.

Comment: i am trying to create that single merged dictionary, as it may come in handy for other reports. You also gave me idea that there could be multiple initiatives, and each initiative could have multiple items and each item could have multiple attributes. So a single dictionary could suffice not only for that report, but other similar reports for comparison of attributes e.g. similar/dissimilar attributes across items etc. Looping dictionary/collection and spitting out data is not the problem, but arranging this merged data into a hierarchical order in dictionary is what i want to achieve first.